# Boto SQS fetching large numbers of messages

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, boto, botocore

I have a python app that is supposed to read all the messages from the queue, and then process them after all the messages have been added to a list.
Once the process is complete it deletes the messages in batch.

The app works perfectly for up to 100K messages however while doing a load test for more than 500K messages.

I got the following error

```
botocore.errorfactory.OverLimit: An error occurred (OverLimit) when calling the ReceiveMessage operation: 

Too many messages have been received without being deleted
```

I understand that this is because I am trying to fetch a large number of messages without deleting them, What I want to know is if there is a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quota limit is around 120K. You can increase the quota with a support request.

> For most standard queues (depending on queue traffic and message
> backlog), there can be a maximum of approximately 120,000 inflight
> messages (received from a queue by a consumer, but not yet deleted
> from the queue). If you reach this quota while using short polling,
> Amazon SQS returns the OverLimit error message. If you use long
> polling, Amazon SQS returns no error messages. To avoid reaching the
> quota, you should delete messages from the queue after they're
> processed. You can also increase the number of queues you use to
> process your messages. To request a quota increase, submit a support
> request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-queues.html